# extern inline functions in C++ for performance

Tags: c++, objective-c

I have the following scenario
I have a .cpp file (I need to use these actually in Objective-C++ .mm):

```
#include <utility>

bool g_ready;
std::pair<int, bool> g_pair;

extern inline bool& isReady()
{
    return g_ready;
}
extern inline std::pair<int, bool>& GetPair()
{
    return g_pair;
}

extern inline void SetPair(int i, bool b)
{
    g_pair.first = i;
    g_pair.second = b;
}
```

And then I use these somehere in another .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>

extern inline bool& isReady();

extern inline std::pair<int, bool>& GetPair();

extern inline void SetPair(int i, bool b);

void update()
{
    if (isReady())
    {
         SetPair(5, false);
         std::cout << "<" << GetPair().first << "," << GetPair().second << ">" << std::endl;
         SetPair(1, true);
         std::cout << "<" << GetPair().first << "," << GetPair().second << ">" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I need these functions to be called in an Update loop called every frame. Is this an optimal solution. Will these be actually inlined without any runtime overhead?

Edit: The production compiler is Clang for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this an optimal solution.

No. Inline functions must be defined in every translation unit that uses them, whether or not they have external linkage (which they will by default, without needing to specify `extern`). Your code gives me a link error for that reason.

> Will these be actually inlined without any runtime overhead?

That depends on the compiler. Short `inline` functions (which must be defined in the same unit as the call) typically will be; functions in other translation units can only be inlined if the compilers supports link-time optimisation.

Comment: I edited the code online. Maybe I did something wrong but mine version  compiles and runs for me. In my case these functions will be used just once because I need to log an event before the logger is instantiated. So I cannot think of a better solution. We use MSVC for development but the production release will be compiled by Clang.

Comment: @Zingam: Some compilers might be able to link it despite the ODR violation, others won't. You'll need to define the inline functions either in the source file that uses them (if there's just one), or a header included from each file that uses them, for this to work portably.